# Why is np.where not returning '1'? Only returns '0'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This code should return a new column called `orc_4` with the value of `1` if the value of the row in `df['indictment_charges']` contains `2907.04` or `0` if not.

Instead it is returning all 0's

```
for index, item in enumerate(df.indictment_charges):
    s = '2907.04' 
    if s in str(item):
        df['orc_4'] = np.where(item == s, 1, 0)
```

Why won't it return 1?

Example output for df.indictment_charges:

```
['2903.112907.022907.042907.04']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are first checking if the item contains the string, but then in `np.where` you are checking if the values are equal (`item == s`), which is obviously different. In addition, you set the whole column equal to the value from `np.where` (and overwriting it after each row), which results in the whole column getting the value based on the final row of the dataframe.
To avoid looping over the rows (which is relatively quite slow) you can use `pandas.Series.str.contains` to check if a string contains a certain value like this:

```
df["orc_4"] = np.where(df["indictment_charges"].str.contains("2907.04"), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Decently slow running over 73,000 rows, but it got the job done thank you for the quick answer.